# Clojure: import java class dynamically

Tags: java, clojure

Suppose I define such clojure function:

```
(defn print-this [this] (println "print this: " this))
```

If I use the function in repl:

```
(print-this that)
```

I would end up with:

```
print this: that
nil
```

as output.

Now if I make such definition:

```
(defn import-by-name [name] (import (some.package.value name)))
```

and use the function in repl:

```
(import-by-name "SomeClassName")
```

I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: some.package.value.name (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

where I would expect that "name" be replaced by "SomeClassName" instead. If I type:

```
(import (some.package.value SomeClassName))
```

everything works as expected.

Why is it that [name] is not interpreted in the import-by-name function above?
Is it possible to dynamically import a java class from a variable value? If so how? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import` is a macro, so any symbols you pass to it will be taken literally.

```
(macroexpand '(import (some.package.value name)))

;; => (do (clojure.core/import* "some.package.value.name"))
```

**Literals**

For string literals, and by extension collection literals, you can use a macro to accomplish what you are describing.

```
(defmacro import-by-name [name] `(import '[some.package.value ~name]))

(import-by-name "ClassName") ;; => nil
```

**Vars**

For importing classes from a var, you have to start dipping into the internals of namespaces.

```
(defn import-by-name [n]
  (.importClass (the-ns *ns*)
                (clojure.lang.RT/classForName (str "some.package.value." n))))
```

There might be a cleaner way, and I will update this answer if I find one.

Comment: Just be aware, there are limits. Passing it a string works, but passing it a var will just append the symbol. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there anyway to do a similar thing with a var? The goal is to interface clojure code with a large xjc-generated java library from a fairly complex xsd.

Comment: Are you trying to implement the equivalent of `import some.package.*`, or are you reading this list from a file?

Comment: No. It could be list from a file or a command-line argument. I want to import a small subset of classes from some.package.value but specify from input (file or command line). Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an attempt at your scenario. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The macro version seems to give "Syntax error macroexpanding..." with `failed: simple-symbol? at: [:package-list :quoted-spec :spec :classes]` in Clojure 1.10.0. I needed to `(let [s (symbol name)] \`(import '[some.package.value ~s])))`.